# Excel 12.0 Interop acting randomly on Excel 2016 using C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-2016

I have written C# application using Excel Interop 12.0 that worked fine on Excel 2007 and Excel 2010. But it is working randomly on Excel 2016. It gives Activate method of Range class failed error sometimes. When I rerun the program it is ok. Again I run it throws error. The program opens about 30 workbooks and populates the workbook from C#. I use Range.get_ReSize() and Range.Activate() in many places. Why is the behavior random? Any Help is appreciated

````
xlWb.Activate(); 
xlWsSummary.Activate(); 
Excel.Range ra = xlWsSummary.UsedRange;//append to the last cell in the used range ra.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, System.Type.Missing).Activate(); 

Excel.Range Range; 
string cellToPaste = "A" + (xlApp.ActiveCell.Row + 1).ToString();//go to the next row 
Range = xlWsSummary.get_Range(cellToPaste, System.Type.Missing); 
Range = Range.get_Resize(1, index); 
Range.Value2 = data; 
Range.Font.Size = 8;//set the fontsize ```
````

Comment: I am trying to activate the last cell and then I go to that row plus 1 to append data to the next line. This code had been running until Excel 2010.

Thanks for offering to help me

Comment: I removed the code lines where I have used Range.Activate() and now it passes but then it stops when I use Worsheet.Select at later part of the code. How can I select a worksheet and then the Cell A1,A1 before showing the workbook to the user?

Comment: When I use .Application in front of a Worksheet like Worksheet.Application and then make a Select(), it works fine with 12.0 PIA on Office 365 installed. If I remove the Application property of worksheet and then make a Select method call, it fails. Anyone can help understanding this?

Comment: WHY are you using `Select` at all? Why not work with `Worksheet` objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly, but here is some sample code that works through 2 Excel workbooks, each with a single worksheet containing 6 numbers:

```
         A  B  C
       ----------
    1 |  3  4  5
    2 |  6  7  8
```

This data is copied from each workbook and appended to data in a summary workbook, creating:

```
         A  B  C
       ----------
    1 |  3  4  5
    2 |  6  7  8
    3 |  3  4  5
    4 |  6  7  8
```

Finally, the next 'A' column cell after the data is selected before saving the summary workbook:

````
string file = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Summary.xlsx";
List<string> fileData = new List<string>{@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", 
                                         @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Book2.xlsx"};      
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

// Open summary workbook and init data workbook and worksheet
Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
Excel.Worksheet xlWsSummary = xlWb.Sheets[1];
Excel.Workbook xlWbData = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlWsData = null;

// Work through your data workbooks
for ( int i = 0; i < fileData.Count; i++ )
{
    // Open data workbook
    xlWbData = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileData[i]);
    xlWsData = xlWbData.Sheets[1];

    // Get specific range of data. I didn't use UsedRange in case only a subset of data is required
    string dataStart = "A1";
    string dataEnd = "C2";
    Excel.Range rangeSource = xlWsData.get_Range(dataStart, dataEnd);

    // Determine next available 'A' cell after used range in summary worksheet
    Excel.Range ra = xlWsSummary.UsedRange;
    Excel.Range rangeDest = ra.get_Range("A" + (ra.Rows.Count + 1));

    // Copy data from data workbook to summary workbook
    rangeSource.Copy(rangeDest);

    // Select the range just copied to the summary workbook and format as required
    Excel.Range rangeFormat = rangeDest.Resize[rangeSource.Rows.Count, rangeSource.Columns.Count];
    rangeFormat.Font.Size = 8;//set the fontsize ```
}

// Release data workbook objects and close before doing anything else
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWsData);
xlWbData.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWbData);

// Select next available cell in A column
xlWsSummary.Activate();
Excel.Range used = xlWsSummary.UsedRange;
Excel.Range next = xlWsSummary.get_Range("A" + (used.Rows.Count + 1));
next.Select();

// Save the file
xlWb.SaveAs(file);

// And, release!
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWsSummary);
xlWb.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWb);
````

I may have not handled the Excel object releasing properly so you'd better look into that and the Activate() call gives an ambiguity warning but otherwise, hope this helps.